# Isn't past simple in this exercise also correct?

Tags: tense, past-tense, past-vs-past-perfect

The sentence is as follows:

> You see, when Elvis died, he _ (already, be) super famous for years.

You have to use the verb in the bracket and put it into the right tense. I've used the past simple, which would be:

> You see, when Elvis died, he already was super famous for years.

But the key states otherwise:

> You see, when Elvis died, he had already been super famous for years.

Was i completely wrong or is my answer also viable?

Comment: If you're going to include (syntactically highly questionable) ***super famous*** it probably doesn't make much difference how you phrase the rest of the text. But to be "valid", you need the Past Perfect verb form: ***...had already been** [very, extremely] famous for years.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "for years" (combined with the meaning and context) makes past perfect necessary, since it's about a period of time. If we had:

> When Elvis died, he was very famous

... then that could be okay; it's describing his fame at that moment. And if we had:

> After Elvis rose to fame, he was famous for many years

... then it's okay too; we're talking about a period of time, but it comes after the moment that happens in the first half of the sentence.

But in our example, we have a moment ("when Elvis died"), and a period of time that came *before* that moment, and that's what past perfect is made for.